# Flurry AppCircle Clips: out of videos during testing?

Tags: flurry

I'm recently playing around with the Flurry AppCircle Clips SDK, but during my test the SDK ran out of videos to play... According to their FAQ the cap of the video frequency is predetermined by the Advertisers based on their daily budget. I can only view new clips after a 24hrs roll.

This is painful and slows down my development, does anyone know if there is a sandbox mode for the Clips SDK that plays unlimited test videos? If not then how can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clips supports a test mode just like the regular AppCircle ads. In test mode you won't be generating revenue but there should be more videos available, however it's not unlimited. At the moment you can't set this yourself and will need to contact either your account mgr or support@flurry.com.

(disclaimer: I work on the Android SDK at Flurry)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I figured that when my support contact replied me :)